# Rspec feature test with sidekiq mail delivery, how to wait for mail observer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, sidekiq

when I send a mail through `deliver_later` it is managed by sidekiq, and then my registered mail observer is triggered.

I have a Capybara test that checks states changed inside observer code, but it fails randomly if observer is not executed right after the clicks, and the expectation doesn't work correctly.

Example:

```
# spec
scenario 'Test that fails randomly' do
  click_link "Go!"
  # MyModel#done is a boolean attribute, so we have #done? method availiable
  expect(MyModel.first.done?).to be true
end

# The controller that manages the Go! link, triggers a mailer.
# After the mailer, this is executed.
# Registered observer
def delivered_mail(mail)
  email = Email.find_by_message_id mail.message_id
  email.user.update_attributes done: true
end
```

Fun fact: If I execute this scenario isolated, the test will always pass.
If I execute the test suite completely, the test will 9:1 fail:pass more or less. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Tried putting this in rails_helper:

```
require 'sidekiq/testing'
RSpec.configure do |config|
  Sidekiq::Testing.inline!
end
```

And also putting `Sidekiq::Testing.inline!` in the very first line of the `scenario` block... nothing. The same fun fact.

#### Update:

Added `database_cleaner` gem, and now it fails everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actions in Capybara (`click_link`, etc) know nothing about any behaviors they trigger.  Because of this there is no guarantee as to what the app will have done after your `click_link` line returns, other than the link will have been clicked, and the browser will have started to perform whatever that action triggers.  Your test then immediately checks 'MyModel.first.done?` while the browser could still be submitting a request (This is one reason why directly checking database records in feature tests is generally frowned upon).

The solution to that (and end up with tests that will work across multiple drivers reliably is to check for a visual change on the page that indicates the action has completed.  You also need to set up ActiveJob properly for testing so you can make sure the jobs are executed.  To do this you will need to `include ActiveJob::TestHelper`, which can be done in your RSpec config or individual scenarios, and you will need to make sure  `ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test` is set (can be done in config/environment/tests.rb file if wanted).  Then assuming your app shows a message "Mail sent!" on screen when the action has completed you would do

```
include ActiveJob::TestHelper 
ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapater = :test
...
perform_enqueued_jobs do
  click_link "Go!"
  expect(page).to have_text('Mail sent!') # This will wait for the message to appear, which guarantees the action has completed and enqueued the job
end # when this returns any jobs enqueued during the block will have been executed

expect(MyModel.first.done?).to be true
```

Comment: I've thinked of that before (tried it in fact), but doesn't work. The page keeps having 'Mail sent!' before `MyModel.first.done?` becomes true, because the attribute update is done inside an Observer class, which is triggered right after the email is sent (which can occur after the page is shown because the email is only queued).

Comment: @PedroAdameVergara With that architecture you probably want to look at including `ActiveJob::TestHelper`, setting `ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test`, and then wrap the test before your final expectation in `perform_enqueued_jobs` so that you are guaranteed the jobs have been executed before the expectation runs -  You'll still need the `have_text` because that showing up will guarantee the job has been queued.

Comment: You don't realize how much I love you. I cannot believe it finally worked after a whole day. Thank you! That did the trick, although I didn't need `have_text` Please add it as a reply and I'll accept it.

Comment: @PedroAdameVergara Updated the answer - I'd recommend keeping the `have_text` it will prevent flakiness, especially if you ever want to swap to a different driver.